# A question about linear application

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, we have two vector space V, W, and X is a K-base of V.

So, therefore if we have $f,g: V \to W$ two K-linear applications. Suppose f(x)=g(x) for all $x \in X$, how to prove $f=g$?

And for all $x \in X$, if we have $w \in W$, can we show there exist a unique linear application $h: V \to W$ such that $h(x) = w$.

Sorry, it's truly a basic question, but I'm a beginner so I don't know how to solve that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look that for being $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ a $K$-base of $V$, then every element $v \in V$ can be written in an unique way as
$$
v=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n
$$
for $a_1,...,a_n \in K$.
For being $f$ and $g$ linear, then
$$
f(v)=f(a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n)=a_1f(x_1)+...+a_nf(x_n)=a_1g(x_1)+...+a_ng(x_n)=g(a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n)=g(v).
$$
Since $v$ is arbitrary, we got the result. The second question is of direct proof with this.

Comment: thanks, it's very clear, i understand now.